# Web api Restful : Get resource by foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

My question is about the "correct way" to name the route in a .NET core web API of the following case:

[image]

- a bank account is always related to a Enterprise.
- a Enterprise can have multiple bank accounts
- a contract has always one bank account

so i have resources like that :

```
/api/enterprise/1 // get enterprise 1
/api/contract/1 // get contract 1
/api/bank-account/1 //get bankaccount  1
```

my question is, what is the best way to get enterprise bank accounts ?

**first idea :**

use query string as a "search-terms"

```
api/bank-account?EnterpriseId=1
```

**second idea**

use child ressource

```
api/enterprise/1/bank-account
```

but if i do that i have multiple "bank-account" in different level, i dont know if is it a good way?

```
api/enterprise/1/bank-account //bank-account level2
api/bank-account //bank-account level1
```

i think the second idea is a good way but i'm not sure if a can manipulate same "model" on different level of the api.

Thank you.
have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at microsoft's example of routing Web API: [Routing in ASP.NET Web Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

I would prefer second idea.With a little polishing

For example:

```
api/enterprise      //return List of enterprise objects if needed
api/enterprise/1    //return specific enterprise with id 1
api/enterprise/1/bank-account    //return list of bank accounts for enterprise with id 1
api/enterprise/1/bank-account/1  //return specific bank account with id 1
```

That is if you want to GET bank account in context of specific enterprise

But if you want to GET bank account only by its id, its better to do

```
api/bank-account/1
```

In this use case you can't really get bank accounts for specific enterprise without adding query string with enterprise id because

```
api/bank-account  //this should return list of bank accounts ALL BANK ACCOUNTS
```

Here's a multilevel controller example for you:

```
[Route("Inventories/{inventoryId}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class InventoryEntriesController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
    
    // GET: Inventories/{inventoryId}/InventoryEntries
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<InventoryEntryDto>>> GetInventoryEntries(int inventoryId)
    {
        ...
    }
    
    // GET: Inventories/{inventoryId}/InventoryEntries/{id}
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<InventoryEntryDto>> GetInventoryEntry(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    // POST: Inventories/{inventoryId}/InventoryEntries
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<InventoryEntryDto>> AddInventoryEntry(InventoryEntryDto inventoryEntryDto)
    {
        ...
    }

    // PUT: Inventories/{inventoryId}/InventoryEntries/{id}
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateInventoryEntry(int id, InventoryEntryDto inventoryEntryDto)
    {
        ...
    }

    // DELETE: Inventories/{inventoryId}/InventoryEntries/{id}
    [Authorize]
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteInventoryEntry(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```